# Is it considered a wash sale if stock is bought twice within 30 days of sale?

Tags: united-states, irs, wash-sale, tax-loss-harvesting

Let's say I bought one unit of ABC stock on March 1, 2024 for $100 and another unit on March 2, 2024 for $100. I sold both units of ABC stock for $80 each on March 14, 2024. Assuming I don't buy ABC again before April 14, 2024 (within 30 days of March 14, 2024), is this considered a wash sale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wash sale is a sale 30 days before or after purchasing replacement stocks. If your purchase replacement stocks 31 days after, then it's not 30 days before or after, and as such - not a wash sale.